# How to solve a problem importing numeric number

Tags: sas, format, informat

I've multiple .csv files like this:

```
20/04/2023;26,46;26,46;25,97;26,25;56922920
19/04/2023;26,84;27;26,22;26,32;35748347
18/04/2023;27;27;26,28;26,84;40704513
17/04/2023;26,6;26,72;26,28;26,61;29563431
14/04/2023;26,47;26,51;26,04;26,38;16890800
```

And I use this code to import:

```
data work.mydataset;
  length filename $100;
  set work.files;
  location=cat("&path",filename);
  infile dummy filevar=location length=reclen end=done missover dlm=';';
  do while (not done);
    informat d1 ddmmyy10. p1 commax10.2 p2 commax10.2 p3 commax10.2 p4 commax10.2 p5 commax16.;
    format d1 date9. p1 commax10.2 p2 commax10.2 p3 commax10.2 p4 commax10.2 p5 commax16.;
    input d1 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

But, in the third row, this code import p1 and p2 as 0.27 instead of 27.00.
Someone could you help me to understand why this error happens?
Thanks.
Tiago.

[example of correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ZoH.png)

Comment: You are clearly NOT a sas developer. The `input` statement automatically creates a loop for the whole `data` step, so you don't need a `while`-`end` block, nor a `done` indicator.

Comment: @DirkHorsten The DO loop is because it is reading from multiple text files.  Notice the SET statement reading in the dataset with the list of filenames.

Comment: I read all log files on our system of the past day at once without do-loop

Answer (score 2):

Why did you tell SAS to divide the numbers that do not have explicit decimal points by 100 if you didn't want it to do that?

Remove the DECIMAL part of the INFORMAT.  That is for telling SAS where to place the implied decimal point.  So it is only wanted when you know that the strings were purposely build without an explicit decimal point to save one character.

In fact since you are reading the values using LIST MODE you can remove the WIDTH part also. In LIST MODE the INPUT statement will ignore the requested format width and just use whole length of the next field it finds.

```
input d1 p1-p5;
informat d1 ddmmyy. p1-p5 commax.;
format d1 date9. p1-p4 commax10.2 p5 commax16.;
```

Note: Displaying a value with COMMAX16. is also a little strange. The 16th position would be another thousands separator.  If you think the numbers might be larger than 999,999,999,999 then use COMMAX17. instead.

Comment: thanks Tom for the solution help and the note. I use 16 to guarantee the maximum value that I have in my dataset.

Comment: So you have a value like -999,999,999,999?  That would require 16 characters. But if you only have positive numbers then to display values up to 999,999,999,999 you only need COMMAX15 and if you need one more digit you have to move to COMMAX17 so there is room for the extra digit and the extra thousands separator.